# how to direct access webroot images in cakephp by hitting url on webpage

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.1

I have images in webroot and i want to access them from url in cakephp

something like :

http: www.abc/cakephp/app/webroot/img/image.jpg

Comment: ```http://www.abc/cakephp/img/image.jpg```

Comment: $this->Html->image('image.jpg');

Answer (score 0):

try this..
A simple image tag

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/foo.gif" .../ >
```

A background image within a table cell the old way:

```
<td background="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/foo.gif">
```